# What is the programming language on Stack Overflow which has the greatest quantity of questions rated with -1 or less?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm curious about programming languages questions on Stack Overflow.

What is the best rated programming language (in terms of positive rated questions)?

What is the worst rated programming language (in terms of negative rated questions)?

Comment: Hello, did you know about [the data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) where you can find answers to this (and all kinds of other data related questions)?

Comment: My guess is that it will be JavaScript for both. (Highest and lowest proportion would probably be a better measure of... whatever it is you're trying to measure.)

Comment: JavaScript or PHP

Comment: @TinyGiant  It's a two-nag race to the bottom:)

Comment: @TimPost I was unaware of data explorer and let me say thanks since It is great! Absolutely I was looking for this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't answer that with [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) but you can look at tags on questions and their score. This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/792412) does that:

```sql
;with pos as
(
select row_number() over(order by count(*) desc) rank
     , count(*) [total positive questions]
     , tagname [postive tags]
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where p.score > 0
group by tagname
)
,neg as
(
select row_number() over(order by count(*) desc) rank
     , count(*) [total negative questions]
     , tagname [negative tags]
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where p.score < 0
group by tagname
)

select pos.*
     , neg.[total negative questions]
     , neg.[negative tags]
from pos
inner join neg on pos.rank = neg.rank
order by 1
```

When run today, SEDE is updated once a week, this is the outcome:

[image: tags and their score, positive and negative]

The commentators under your question weren't far off, so they win a prize. They'll receive their unexplained down votes shortly.

When you're new to the Stack Exchange Data Explorer you might like the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial). Check the [data-explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-explorer) tag on the über-Meta for more queries and info

Comment: Javascript and PHP, followed closely by... Java, C#, android, *and* python.

Comment: When I saw SEDE, I immediately knew it's rene *again*

Comment: I wish I could SEDE, I think the percentage scored (i.e. exclude questions with 0 score) questions that are positive / negative would be much more interesting. This is ultimately just a popularity contest as it is.

Comment: [This is what I came up with](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/792584). I excluded any tags with less than 1000 scored questions because they made the data less interesting, though it did provide a good list of good tags to kill quickly when sorting by most downvoted (a tag with 10 questions being 90% downvoted is a good indicator that it may not need to exist)

Comment: Oh yeah, but percent works a lot better. I would have modified the query myself, but I can't sql. ;_; [calculator] and [indexoutofboundsexception]. Yeesh, that second one sounds like it needs to be burninated.

Comment: Relevant XKCD: https://xkcd.com/1138/

Comment: Why did I receive such number of negative votes? Is this question really that bad?

Comment: @Moreno it is -17/+10 so I wouldn't complain. I think the voters don't find it particular useful to ask for or have those stats. It is better received if you have a meaningful purpose for the outcome. An other option might be lack of effort / research, just as it would be on main. Worth noting that votes on Meta don't cost or gain you any reputation.